# Shell: test if parameter is a directory

Tags: shell, directory

People helped me with sorting my parameter with a litle code
but now I would like to check if this parameter is a directory.

```
   if [ -d "$@" ]
   then
     echo "$@" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort
   else
     echo this is not a valid map!
   fi
```

Normally to check if something is a directory you need to use `[ -d file ]`
But this time it doesn't work.

If you have any ideas or solutions, your free to post!
Ty for reading/helping!

Comment: Hm… If a remember correctly, you script takes a number of strings as parameters. So, what should be a directory?

Comment: `[ -d file ]` is what you will do. How does this not work?

Comment: Neither of the answers have mentioned this: `[ -d "$@" ]` will work only if your script receives exactly one argument -- `"$@"` substitutes the quoted content of *all* arguments -- so if your script received `foo bar baz`, you would be saying `[ -d "foo" "bar" "baz" ]` -- naturally, `test` doesn't know what to do with those extra arguments, and will fail with the message `test: too many arguments`. You want either `"$1"` -- the first argument, only -- or to iterate over `"$@"`, as the current answers suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on kirelagin's suggestion:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    if [ ! -d "$f" ]; then
        echo "Not a dir: $f" >&2
    else
        echo "$f"
    fi
done | sort
```

This will echo all of the non-directory arguments to `stderr` and print the sorted list of directories on `stdout`.

Comment: This is really something interesting but I have 1 more question if possible, I would like to break my code if he finds an item that is not a directory, when I just put "Break" under the echo it won't work. Do you have any idea how you could fix that?

Comment: You could `exit` instead, or instead of echoing the directory names you could store them in a new list.  Then process the new list after all the input has been validated.

Answer (score 3):

```
for f in "$@"; do
    if [ ! -d "$f" ]; then
        echo "Not a dir: $f"
    fi
done
```

This code will iterate over all arguments and output those that are not valid directories. But I'm not sure what you are going to sort now.